# "Could not find developer disk image" when trying to build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When trying to build on my connected iphone, i get the "Could not find developer disk image" error. I have IOS 10.1 and xcode 7.2.1, but can not update xcode because i have yosemite 10.10.5, and 10.11.5 is required for the new version. What to do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Xcode 7.2.1` does not support `iOS 10`. Either update to `Xcode 8` or change the deployment target to `iOS 9.x`.

Comment: Okay, so i have to downgrade my phone again, since i can not update xcode - there is no other solution :( ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don´t think so @L_N

Comment: Okay, sad :( But thanks for the answer :)